# Can’t dismiss a popover normally after it presents a page sheet with isModalInPresentation set to true

Tags: ios, ios13

We have a view controller (A) presented as a popover. When it presents a view controller (B) as a page sheet, we are setting `isModalInPresentation` to true on B to prevent the swipe down gesture from dismissing it. But setting that to true also results in it being changed to true on view controller A. So after the page sheet is dismissed (with `dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`), the popover can’t be dismissed by tapping outside of its bounds.

We tried setting `isModalInPresentation` back to false on B before it is dismised (in its `viewWillDisappear(_:)`), and while that changes `isModalInPresentation` back to false on A, A still cannot be dismissed by tapping outside of its bounds.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be fixed when building with Xcode 11.1 to an iOS 13.1 simulator (the popover is dismissed when tapping outside its bounds, and we don’t need to set `isModalInPresentation` back to false when dismissing B).